# How to turn two nested HashMaps in a Vec of tuples without for loops?

Tags: rust, vector, hashmap, tuples

Take the following data type:

```rust
let mut items = HashMap::<u64, HashMap<u64, bool>>::new();
```

I successfully managed to turn it into a vector of tuples like this:

```rust
let mut vector_of_tuples: Vec<(u64, u64, bool)> = vec![];

for (outer_id, inner_hash_map) in items.iter() {
    for (inner_id, state) in inner_hash_map.iter() {
        vector_of_tuples.push((*outer_id, *inner_id, *state));
    }
}
```

But I want to shrink this code logic, possibly with the help of the [Map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html) and [Zip](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html) functions from the Rust standard library.

How can I achieve the same result without using for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I achieve the same result without using for loops?

You can use `collect()` to build a vector from an iterator without an explicit loop:

```
let vector_of_tuples: Vec<(u64, u64, bool)> = items
    .iter()
    // ...
    .collect();
```

To expand the contents of the inner hash maps into the iterator, you can use `flat_map`:

```
let vector_of_tuples: Vec<_> = items
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|(&outer_id, inner_hash_map)| {
        inner_hash_map
            .iter()
            .map(move |(&inner_id, &state)| (outer_id, inner_id, state))
    })
    .collect();
```

In many cases chaining iterator adapters will yield more understandable code than the equivalent `for` loop because iterators are written in a declarative style and tend not to require side effects. However, in this particular case the original `for` loop might actually be the more readable option. YMMV, the best option will sometimes depend on the programming background of you and other project contributors.